# Issue while creating maven project using command line behind proxy

Tags: maven, testing, proxy

I have added the correct proxy in setting.xml. But when I am running the mvn command to create maven project:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=testDemo -DartifactId=demo1  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I am getting following error. I have tried with different proxies and systems but getting the same error. Also when I am creating maven project in eclipse, getting same error.
Is it a network issue or it can be resolved by some changes in setting.xml.

```
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from http://r
epo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will
not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates a
re forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-m
etadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorize
d by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.278s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 23 17:52:36 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the
 plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the
repositories [local (E:\Maven\m2repo), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/mav
en2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a network issue. Currently your firewall is blocking maven repo `http://repo.maven.apache.org/` I guess you need to update update proxy URL, username and password in `setting.xml`

Also exception is showing `Authentication Required` so I am assuming that proxy credentials are not configured

Comment: I have already updated the proxy url, username, password in setting.xml. In some system it is working but in some system it is not working